# Undeploy war file programmatically (Wildfly 18.x)

Tags: java, jboss, soa

We have decided to use a SOA with multiple war files in one JBoss server.

One service is responsible for orchestration and should be able to shut down other services if requested by admin (through a web interface).

Is it possible to do that with Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WildFly management API for this. https://docs.wildfly.org/19/Admin_Guide.html#Management_Clients